# What's the name of those input boxes which allow multiple autocompleted inputs which then become "buttons" in the textbox when selected?

Tags: forms, input

A perfect example of what im asking is, when asking a question in SO, look at the "Tags" input box. You can type "php" and select from a multitude of "php" tags, then when you select it, "php" becomes a button with an "X".

Im curious what the technical term for this type of input is so I can look if jquery, extjs or various libraries that im using have this.

[image]